# Google API for tags extraction from youtube videos

Tags: video, youtube, tagging

I have extracted tags from the given image using Clarifai and Google Vision APIs. Similar thing I want to achieve for videos.

Can anyone suggest, if there are any APIs available to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Clarifai doesn’t currently analyze youtube links but if given a direct link to videos, our v1 API will give back concepts/tags. You can see the documentation [here](https://developer.clarifai.com/guide-v1/). Hope this will help!